# CS50 Python Fuel Gauge

Tags: python, cs50

I'm facing a problem with Fuel Gauge CS50's. My code's only passing through half of the requirements. Can someone help me with this one?

https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/fuel/#demo

```
My result while trying to check: 

:) fuel.py exists
:) input of 3/4 yields output of 75% - OK
:) input of 1/3 yields output of 33% - OK
:) input of 2/3 yields output of 67% - OK
:) input of 0/100 yields output of E - OK
:) input of 1/100 yields output of E - OK
:) input of 100/100 yields output of F - OK
:) input of 99/100 yields output of F - OK
**:( input of 100/0 results in reprompt - ERROR
    expected program to reject input, but it did not**
:) input of 10/3 results in reprompt - OK
**:( input of three/four results in reprompt - ERROR
    expected program to reject input, but it did not**
**:( input of 1.5/4 results in reprompt - ERROR
    expected program to reject input, but it did not**
**:( input of 3/5.5 results in reprompt - ERROR
    expected program to reject input, but it did not**
**:( input of 5-10 results in reprompt - ERROR
    expected program to reject input, but it did not**
```

My code:

```py
def main ():
    final_fuel = get_percent()
    percent_fuel = round(final_fuel * 100)
    if percent_fuel <= 1:
        print("E")
    elif percent_fuel >= 99:
        print("F")
    else:
        print(f"{percent_fuel}%")


def get_percent():
    try:
        while True:
            fraction = input("Fuel Fraction: ")
            x, y = fraction.split('/')
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
            fuel = x/y
            if fuel <= 1:
                return fuel

    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        pass


main ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getpercent` function has some exception handling, but it doesn't do the right thing when it catches an exception. Rather than asking for a new input, it just gives up and returns `None`.

It's not hard to fix this issue, as you're already catching the right exceptions. You just need to move the `try` and `except` code inside of the `while True` loop, so that after an exception is handled, you keep looping and prompt for a new input.

```
def get_percent():
    while True:
        try:                               # move exception handling inside the loop
            fraction = input("Fuel Fraction: ")
            x, y = fraction.split('/')
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
            fuel = x/y
            if fuel <= 1:                  # you might want to reject negatives here
                return fuel

        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
            pass                           # the loop will now resume after this
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely beat my head against the wall on this one (I'm new to programming) but this is how I completed it. It's not the most elegant way to solve it but got me all green :).

```
def main():
    
    a, b = input("Fraction: ").split("/")
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)

    fuel_left = (a / b) * 100
    fuel_left = round(fuel_left)

    if fuel_left > 101:   #Where I got stuck!
      main() #catches any equation that amounts to over 100% 
             #to restart main()
      
    if fuel_left >= 99 and fuel_left <= 100:
      print("F")
      
    elif fuel_left <= 2:
      print("E")

    else:
      fuel_left = str(fuel_left)
      fuel_left = fuel_left.strip(".0")
      print(f"{fuel_left}%")

while True:
  try:
    main()
    break
    
  except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    pass
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't validate the input - the user can enter whatever they want and you just take their word for it that they've entered the correct thing:

```
fraction = input("Fuel Fraction: ")
# No validation logic before you try to split. What if they forgot to include the /?
x, y = fraction.split('/')

# What if they include a value like 1.5? This will result in 1, and your program would be none the wiser.
x = int(x)

# What if this is 0?
y = int(y)
```

You should validate that the user has entered something sensible. For example, it's evidently expecting you to validate that they haven't entered 0 in the denominator, and that the numerator isn't a decimal number.

The fastest way to do that is probably with a regular expression, like the following:

```
^[0-9]+/[1-9]+$
```

If you haven't covered these yet, you could manually validate it:

```
def validate(string):
   if not '/' in string:
      return False
   
   a, b = string.split('/')

   return a.isnumeric() and b.isnumeric() and int(b) != 0
```

A few general comments: I used `int(b)` to handle the case of repeated zeros (e.g. if the user inputs `00000`). The `isnumeric()` function will check to make sure that the strings are valid integers (so, for example, decimal numbers, empty strings, etc. would cause it to return `False`).

Then, you could repeatedly prompt the user until `validate` returned `True`:

```
fraction = input("Fuel Fraction: ")
while not validate(fraction):
    fraction = input("Please input a valid Fuel Fraction: ")
```

Comment: I understood your comment, but that's exactly the problem. I'm not getting how to do these requirements here to prompt the user again instead of getting an error:

If, though, X or Y is not an integer, X is greater than Y, or Y is 0, instead prompt the user again.

Comment: I mean, for example. If I try something like 'if y == 0:'. What should I put to get prompted again?

Comment: @augustomathhh Basically, you need to write a loop that checks to see if the string is valid and repeatedly prompts the user if it's not. I edited to illustrate this.

Comment: Thank you so much EJoshuaS. I'll try to redo my code. You made some questions clear for me! =)

Comment: Hey EJoshuaS, I just found out that my while True was inside the Try: function and not vice-versa. That was my real problem - except was not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

After catching an exception you need to reprompt user (get input). That will solve your problem (already tested and all tests passed). Add this code:

```
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
fraction = input("Fuel Fraction: ")
pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    fraction_to_percent("Fraction: ")


def fraction_to_percent(prompt):
     while True:
        try:
            numerator, denominator = input(prompt).split("/")
            result = int(numerator) / int(denominator)
        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
            pass
        else:
            if result > 1:
                continue
            elif result == 1 or result == (99/100):
                print("F")
                break
            elif result == (1/100) or result == (0/100):
                print("E")
                break
            print(round(result * 100), '%', sep='')
            break

main()
```

Comment: What does this code do? Read [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how [SO] works, and don't forget to [edit] your answer to explain how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but I just worked on this problem myself and came up with a seemingly simpler solution:

```
def main():
    frac = get_valid_frac()
    perc = get_perc(frac)

    print(perc)


def get_valid_frac():
    while True:
        try:
            # Prompt the user to input a fraction
            fraction = input("Fraction: ")

            # Split fraction so that we can evaluate conditions: 1) both x and y need to be integers,
            # 2) x <= y, and 3) y > 0

            # Verbose way of coding this (I did this initially):
            # x, y = fraction.split("/")
            # x = int(x)
            # y = int(y)

            # Better way of coding this is to use the map() function
            # This built-in function applies a specific function (here: int()) to an
            # iterable (e.g., list, tuple, string)
            x, y = map(int, fraction.split("/")) # This evaluates the first condition

            if x <= y > 0: # This circumvents the need to capture any ZeroDivisionError, and
                           # also ensures that x is never greater than y
                return(round(x / y * 100)) # # Calculate percentage
        except (ValueError):
            pass


def get_perc(frac):
    if frac < 2:
        return("E")
    elif frac > 98:
        return("F")
    else:
        return(f"{frac}%")


main()
```

I left some comments in between the code lines because I think they convey useful information.

Answer (score 0):

These is one way to solve the fuel problem set

```
    while True :
try:
    user = input("Fraction: ")

    x,y = user.split("/")

    new_x = int(x)
    new_y = int(y)

    result = round(new_x / new_y *100)

    if new_x > new_y:
        continue

    elif result >= 99:
        print("F")

    elif result <= 1 :
        print("E") 

    else:

        print( str(result) + "%")

except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    pass

else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to solve it `\_(-_-)_/` with all checked and approved

```
def fuel_gauge():
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("Enter the fuel level (x/y): ")
        x, y = map(int, user_input.split('/'))
        fuel_conversion(x,y)
        break
    except (ZeroDivisionError,ValueError):
        pass
def fuel_conversion(a,b):
operation = round((a / b) * 100)
if operation <= 100:
    if operation <= 1:
        print('E')
    elif operation >= 99:
        print('F')
    else:
        print(f'{int(operation)}%')
else:
    fuel_gauge()

fuel_gauge()
```